# How to create a new file in every iteration of a PHP program?

Tags: php, file-io

I am creating a file using PHP but I am unable to create a new file in every execution of the application. I am generating an XML file using a database. I want a new file in every execution of my code, how can I do that?

This is my code:

```
<?php
$config['mysql_host'] = "localhost";
$config['mysql_user'] = "root";
$config['mysql_pass'] = "root";
$config['db_name']    = "dcu";
$config['table_name'] = "readingsThreePhase";
//$config['table_name1'] = "miosD1";

mysql_connect($config['mysql_host'],$config['mysql_user'],$config['mysql_pass']);

@mysql_select_db($config['db_name']) or die( "Unable to select database");

function writeMsg()
{
//echo "Hello world!";
$xml          = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>";
$root_element = $config['table_name']."D1"; 
$xml         .= "<$root_element>";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM dcu.readingsThreePhase where meterId=3 order by recordTime DESC limit 1";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
{
   while($result_array = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
   {
      //$xml .= "<".$config['table_name'].">\n";
      $xml .= "<".$config['miosD1'].">\n";


      foreach($result_array as $key => $value)
      {


            if($value==NULL)
           {
            continue;
            } 

         $xml .= "<$key>";


           $xml .= "$value";


         $xml .= "</$key>\n";
      }

  $xml.="</".$config['miosD1'].">";
   }
}

$xml .= "</$root_element>";
header ("Content-Type:text/xml");

echo $xml;

$file=fopen("xmlfilefirst.xml","a");

fwrite($file,$xml);
fclose($file);
}

writeMsg();


$xml          = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>";
$root_element = $config['table_name']."s"; 
$xml         .= "<$root_element>";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM dcu.readingsThreePhase where meterId=3 order by recordTime DESC limit 1";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
{
   while($result_array = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
   {
      $xml .= "<".$config['table_name'].">\n";


      foreach($result_array as $key => $value)
      {


            if($value==NULL)
           {
            continue;
            } 

         $xml .= "<$key>";


           $xml .= "$value";


         $xml .= "</$key>\n";
      }

      $xml.="</".$config['table_name'].">";
   }
}

$xml .= "</$root_element>";
header ("Content-Type:text/xml");

echo $xml;

$file=fopen("xmlfilefirst.xml","a");

fwrite($file,$xml);
fclose($file);

?>
```

Comment: `fopen($new_filename, 'a')` instead of your hardcoded filename.

Comment: Everything in `writeMsg()` seems to have been duplicated after the function is called - you'll probably want to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

use `file_put_contents`

This function is identical to calling fopen(), fwrite() and fclose() successively to write data to a file.
If filename does not exist, the file is created. Otherwise, the existing file is overwritten, unless the FILE_APPEND flag is set.

Answer (score 1):

To create a new file every time, you need a way to generate a unique filename.  You can either create this name with some sort of gibberish, such as:

```
do {
    $filename = 'my_file_' . substr(md5(time( ), 0, 8 ) . '.xml';
} while( file_exists( $filename ) );
```

Or, you can attempt with some sort of numeric naming convention ('myfile1.xml', 'myfile2.xml', 'myfile3.xml' etc).  This would mean getting a listing of the current directory.  If no files are present, start with 1.  Otherwise, start with the count of files + 1 and name your file with that.

See also the documentation for [fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php).  Most of the modes will attempt to create a file if the specified filename does not exist, so just coming up with a unique filename is the trick.